# Given a unit vector $u$, is it possible to find a vector $v$ such that $u \cdot v = − 3$ and $\|v\|= 2$?

Tags: vectors

I have this question but I cannot solve it can anybody help me please:

> Given a unit vector  $u$, is it possible to find a vector $v$ such that $u \cdot v = − 3$ and $\|v\|= 2$? Give an example or explain why this can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a vector v and you are looking for u.v v can be decomposed into a component tangent with u let's call it vt and another one orthogonal to u, let's call it vn. ie: v=vt+vn
u.v=u.(vt+vn)=u.vt
so what does really matter here is vt and u.
we want vt.u=-3 => vt has an opposite direction of u and ||u.vt||=|-3|=3
or

||u.vt|| =||u||.||vt||=||vt|| => ||vt||=3 => vt=-3
the norm of v is: ||v||=square-root(vt^2+vn^2)>=|vt|=3
so the norm of v can't be less than 3

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $|u\cdot v|\leq \|u\|\|v\|$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.